# How to get the json data used in each curl statement while using xargs and maps it to its corresponding result?

Tags: shell-script, shell, curl, xargs, jq

I have text file that has arguments of curl command. This is how the file looks

```
'https://example.com/tl/' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"email":"username2",}'
'https://example.com/tl/' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"email":"username3",}'
'https://example.com/tl/' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"email":"username4",}'
'https://example.com/tl/' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"email":"username5",}'
'https://example.com/tl/' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"email":"username6",}'
```

This is the command I use

`cat /AbsolutePath/Inputfile.txt | xargs -P 10000 -n 10 curl -s | jq '.message'`

I'm using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), to parse json in command line

What I want is,

1. Pipe or send output of above command to another command, so that if `message` has certain text, grab the email **value** used in that corresponding curl command and write to a log file or create a filename with usernameX.txt

For example, only if username2 and username5 cURL command's message = 'success', these two usernames should be written to a log file or two files username2.txt and username5.txt should be created.

Comment: 1. why `-P 10000`?  Does your system have 10,000 CPU cores?  Extremely unlikely, but if it does, do you want to bombard the remote server with 10,0000 simultaneous requests? and expect not to get your IP address blocked?  2.  Why `-n 10`? There aren't 10 args on each line.  and xargs won't handle them the way you seem to think it does. 3. you'd be better off running curl from xargs inside a `sh -c` script. Or instead of xargs, use gnu parallel or even a simple for loop. 4. do you mean to pipe all of xargs' output into jq in one go (as you're currently doing), or once for each curl command?

Comment: 1. My system doesn't have that many cores. Do you think using `gnu parallel` can send 10000 requests despite computer having normal quad/octa core? I'm doing stress testing on my servers, so no worries on ip blocking. 2. I still couldn't wrap my head around -n and maxprocs. Is this `-X POST` considered as one argument?

Comment: Each line will be treated as 7 arguments by xargs.  The single quotes will be removed.  There are better tools for stress testing a web server, including [ab (Apache Benchmark tool)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/ab.html).  You don't say what unix-like OS you're using but on Debian, `ab` is in the `apache2-utils` package. Other Linux distros probably have it in a similarly-named package.

Comment: A) Sorry I'm lost now. From where the number 7 come into picture? Is it based on my example input?
B) I already spent 2 days juddling between xargs and gnu parallel. Just test gnu parallel in my local machine. DEfault Ubuntu OS that comes with AWS Ec2 instances is my target machine. But thanks for suggesting `ab`. I did hear about it.

Comment: Do you think Ubuntu OS with say ~24cores can handle(send) 10000 reqs/second?

Comment: Yes, from your sample input.    I have no idea if a 24 core machine can handle sending and processing 10000 simultaneous requests (which is **not** the same thing as 10000 reqs/sec - it's 10,000 instances of `curl` being started in parallel, for however long that takes to run). It depends on the machine specs and the nature of the requests. it doesn't seem likely with 10000 forks of curl.    Rather than re-invent the wheel from scratch, I suggest you do some research on existing tools and existing work in the field.

Answer (score 0):

To meet you requirement, each "message" of the output needs to be associated with its corresponding inputted "mail".

The easy way may be replacing the curl with your own shell script that can output both the given mail and its curl result.
A simple, unsafe version maybe like this

```
#! /bin/bash
# print <mail> <message> 
jq .mail -rj "${@: -1]}"      # print mail without newline
echo -n " "                  
curl -s "$@" | jq .message -r
```

Then pipe the result to `awk '$2=="success"{print $1}'`

Other than that, you may try this

```
cat /AbsolutePath/Inputfile.txt |
    xargs -P 10000 -n 10 curl -s |
    jq -s 'to_entries|.[]|select(.value.message=="success")|.key+1' |
    awk 'FILENAME=="-"{line[$0]=1}  FILENAME != "-" && line[FNR]==1{print gensub(/.*--data-raw /, "", "g", $0)}' - /AbsolutePath/Inputfile.txt | 
    jq .mail -r
```

Basically, the jq get the indexes of success messages and the awk reads the indexes and retrieves the last part of corresponding nth line from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to use simple `awk` script.

#### awk script

```
awk '{system("curl "$0)}' /AbsolutePath/Inputfile.txt | jq
```

#### awk script filtering success message

```
awk '{system("curl "$0)}' /AbsolutePath/Inputfile.txt | grep "success"
```

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR

```bsh
cat input.txt |
  xargs -P0 -L1 sh -c 'curl -s "$@" | jq -c --arg username $(echo "${@: -1}" | jq -r .email) "{\$username, message}"' sh |
  jq -r 'select(.message == "success") | .username'
```

## How

You requested to print username depending on its corresponding response body, but your input file are composed of `curl` arguments and you didn't mention whether or not the response body contains username.

Thus I decide to parse your last argument to get username first, for example:

```bsh
cat input.txt |
  xargs -P0 -L1 sh -c 'curl -s "$@" | jq -c --arg username $(echo "${@: -1}" | jq -r .email) "{\$username, message}"' sh
```

```
{"username":"username2","message":"failure"}
{"username":"username4","message":"failure"}
{"username":"username3","message":"success"}
{"username":"username5","message":"failure"}
{"username":"username6","message":"success"}
```

After you retrieved a list of JSON object composed of username and message pair, we can easily filter the steam by the following command:

```bsh
jq -r 'select(.message == "success") | .username'
```

```bsh
cat input.txt |
  xargs -P0 -L1 sh -c 'curl -s "$@" | jq -c --arg username $(echo "${@: -1}" | jq -r .email) "{\$username, message}"' sh |
  jq -r 'select(.message == "success") | .username'
```

```
username3
username6
```

FYI here is the Ruby HTTP server I used for debugging.

```bsh
rackup -rjson -b 'run ->(_) { [200, {}, [JSON.dump(message: rand(2) == 0 ? "success" : "failure")]] }'
```